# Why do tag wiki revision history pages have an "answered by" box?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

Take [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8198083/8), for example.

It shows my edit -- good.

But below the edit, there is an "answered by" box, containing the name and stats for the user who [first wrote an excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8198083/2), for the time [the community user created the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8198083/1).

I don't think the "answered by" box should appear on tag wiki / tag wiki excerpt pages.

Comment: [first rev](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8198083/1) also shows that it was answered by Community...

Comment: It's because a tag wiki is a post, like a question and answer - it's the way it's stored in the DB.

Comment: @Ben But there is server-side code (presumably on that very page) that is generating said "answered by" box. It shouldn't matter what the database side looks like.

Comment: I would guess the /revisions page is a generic page that interacts with all revisions the same- it's not custom to the tag wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by suppressing the blue box when viewing revisions of "wiki" posts. This change will appear in build 3763 for MSE/MSO, and build 2884 for other sites.